# Conversion of eloquent result to use with c3.js

Tags: laravel-blade, c3.js, laravel-5.6

I need to generate a pie chart whose output will be a representation of eloquent output.

My query is:

```
$data = MyModel::select('province_id', DB::raw('COUNT(id) AS cnt'))
    ->groupBy('province_id')
    ->get();
```

`dd($data)` gives me:

[image]

Then it is passed to blade view as:

```
return view('tool.charts', ['data' => $data]);
```

In my blade view (js code is embedded in `<script>` tag):

```
var datax = {!! json_encode($data) !!};

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#pie1',
    data: {
        columns: datax,
        type : 'pie',
    }
});
```

But this doesn't draw the pie chart. If I use hardcoded values, like:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#pie2',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30],['data2', 140],['data3', 40],['data4', 170],
        ],
        type : 'pie',
    }
});
```

It shows the chart as expected.

**UPDATE**:

`column` was changed to `json` and still has no luck.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#pie1',
    data: {
        json: datax,
        type : 'pie',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pie chart is a bit different comparing to others (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30886203/3256489) similar question).

For your case, I would suggest this:

- In your controller, get data as json

> ```
> public function myjson(Request $request){
>     $data = MyModel::selectRaw('province_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt')
>         ->groupBy('province_id')
>         ->get();
>
>     return response()->json($data->toArray());
> }
> ```

- define a route to access on this controller. Add this to your route:

> Route::get('my/json', ['as'=> 'my.json', 'uses'
>   =>’MyController@myjson']);

- Then define your chart inside a blade using AJAX (Not passing variable from controller like you did)

> ```
> <script language="JavaScript">
>     $(document).ready(function () {
>         $.ajax({
>             type: "GET",
>             url: '{{route('my.json')}}',
>             data: "{}",
>             contentType: "application/json",
>             dataType: "json",
>             async: "true",
>             cache: "false",
>             success: function (result) {
>                 OnSuccess(result);
>             },
>             error: function (xhr, status, error) {
>                 alert(error);
>             }
>         });
>     });
>
>     function OnSuccess(response) {
>         var data = {};
>         var lists = [];
>         response.forEach(function (e) {
>
>             lists.push(e.province_id);
>             data[e.province_id] =  e.cnt;
>         });
>
>         var chart1 = c3.generate({
>             bindto: '#pie1',
>             data: {
>                 json: [data],
>                 type : 'pie',
>                 keys: {
>                     value: lists
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>     };
>
> </script>
> ```